# Why are DLLs Missing from Azure Deployment when Copy-Local is set True?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have an ASP.NET MVC v4 project setup in Visual Studio 2013.

I am hosting the project in Git using Visual Studio Online. I have created a build definition using an Azure deployment profile so that I can run an automated build which also automatically deploys the site.

However, after an apparently successful deployment, I am getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked the website via FTP and the System.Web.Mvc.dll file is certainly missing.

However, MVC was installed as a NuGet package, NuGet Package Restore is enabled for the solution and 'Copy Local' is set for the reference. If I build the solution locally, then the DLL is copied to the output folder correctly.

I have checked the Visual Studio Online build log and can see the following...

> ...
>
> Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0'.
>
> ...
>
> Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0'.
>
> ...

So - I'm at a loss as to why the DLL isn't being deployed to Azure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the build drop? If you download the bits that were deployed isbthe file in there?

Answer (score 0):

The latest MVC 4 version is 4.0.0.1. Check that your Project reference is correctly pointing to the version from NuGet, and not the version in your GAC.

This MSDN blog post may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

You could also try adding a redirect to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```